# Can we send push notification automatically to users whenever record entered in firestore database?

Tags: firebase, notifications, google-cloud-firestore, push

i am creating my database in firestore which contains user information - Now i also  want to send push notification to users. Is there any way whenever user record is entered in firestore database push notification is automatically sent to that user?
i also saving user device token id in database....

Comment: This is a perfect example of a time you would use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions).

Comment: Thanks - I studied it - and it solved my issue.